# In sysctl.conf settings, what is the difference between 'all' & 'default'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, kernel

In context of  sysctl.conf settings, 
what is the difference between (`all` vs. `default`) like `net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route` & `net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route`  in sysctl settings ?

If I added `all` values, is it necessary to add `default` as well ?

---

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90443/sysctl-proc-sys-net-ipv46-conf-whats-the-difference-between-all-defau

Comment: [?net.ipv4.conf.all vs net.ipv4.conf.default](https://www.google.com/search?q=net.ipv4.conf.all+vs+net.ipv4.conf.default)

Answer (score 1):

`all` is for all routes, while `default` is only for default route.